# Correct technique for multi string legato pull-offs

Tags: electric-guitar, technique, legato

[image]

*Here I tabbed out the tablature of legato line on two string i.e. G and D String.*

I am self taught intermediate guitar player, still learning. I am trying to figure  out solution or correct way to play this. Please help experienced legato masters. :P

My interpretation of playing this legato line:

**Way 1**: First I keep my 1st, 3rd and 4th finger on 5,7 and 8 fret respectively on G string. Now while keeping my fingers on these three frets, I pluck 8 fret on G string then I do pull off to 7th fret and then again pull off to 5th fret. And while jumping on D string, I again place my 1st, 3rd and 4th finger on 5,7 and 8 fret and do same as did earlier(pulling off one by one).

*Problem:* The jumping on D string and placing my 3 fingers on 3 frets and pulling off takes time and sloppy play.

---

**Way 2**:First step I put my 4th finger in 8th fret on G String(the 1st and 3rd finger not necessarily on fret) and I pluck the G string and as soon as I am going to pull off I am immediately place by 3rd finger on 7 fret and do pull off. And did similar for D String.

*Problem:* The energy during pull off is lost and leads to less powerful pull off.

Now, please tell me correct way to do this, is way 1 or way 2 correct or please tell you way.

Thank you.

PS: Sorry for bad English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couple of ideas for you. Keep index finger on *both* strings, fret 5, like a mini barre. Play G string 8, pull off to 7, pull off to 5. same the on D string, without releasing index finger until all six notes have been played.

Alternatively, don't do a pull off between 8 and 7. Instead do a slide. Then you can pull off to 5, and repeat on D string.

Done properly, I don't believe there will be a difference in sound. Should go without saying that it all needs playing slowly at first - pull offs certainly will sound slowly - there's no need to play a pull off quickly. And slides don't need speed particularly. And hammer ons don't need the previous note even to be played!

It's good that you find different solutions. Both pull off and slide  constitute 'legato', as does hammer on. You may even want to experiment with hammering on the 5th fret notes after an 8-7 slide or pull off. All's fair in love and war (and guitar techniques)!

Comment: I will surely follow this,  what about way 2, any problem in that?  Thank you for answer.

Comment: Won't work as well, usually. Rather weak.